# Django App - allowing users to save their favorite posts to their profile for quick access

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a Django app that is essentially a database for different gym workouts. It allows users to search for workouts, and I anticipate that as scale increases, it would be annoying to keep searching for the same workout the user wants to learn about.

Is there functionality in Django to let the user 'save' a certain workout so it appears on their profile page, almost like a playlist of sorts?

Comment: What is a "profile page"? Do you have a profile model? What does your `Workout` model look like? Please post more context.

Comment: My apologies.. I'm more in the concept testing stage rather than hardcode. I wanted to know if the functionality existed before coding and getting stuck halfway. To clarify, it would be like Instagram's 'save' function, so user can save a post then see all saved posts in a separate page.

Comment: There is no built-in "profile" or "profile page" concept in Django. You will have to implement everything from scratch, or search for a third party package. From a conceptual point of view what you are describing is a simple many-to-many relation between the User (or Profile) model and your Workout model.